# Kotlin and ?.let: how to choose variants of variable's fields?

Tags: kotlin, let, elvis-operator

I have a class:

```
class Clazz(
    val name: String?,
    val value0: String,
    val value1: String?,
    val value2: String
)
```

I want to print `value0`  if we have non-null name. But if `name` is null, then i want return `value1` only if it is not null. if it is, return `value2`.

i do it in `let` way:

```
val result =
            clazz.name?.let {
                return clazz.value0
            } ?: run {
                clazz.value1 ?: clazz.value2
            }
```

but i think it is quite shitty code and it could be done better and simplier.
Is it such a way?

Comment: I think `when` is a better and more readable choice in this case.

Comment: Btw you don't need the second run: `clazz.name?.let { clazz.value0 } ?: clazz.value1 ?: clazz.value2`

Comment: A couple of errors here.  `clazz value0` should be `clazz.value0`, and `value1` and `value2` need `clazz.` qualifiers too. (Unless it's an instance method. Or put it all in a `with()` or similar.) Also the `return` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Try below code it will work:

**Code:**

```
val result: String = when {
            clazz.name.isNullOrEmpty() -> {
                clazz.value1 ?: clazz.value2
            }
            else -> {
                clazz.value0
            }
        }
```

**Explanation:**

```
val result: String = when {
            // check name is null --> true
            clazz.name.isNullOrEmpty() -> {

                // check value1 is not null, if null then return value2

                clazz.value1 ?: clazz.value2 
            }
            else -> { // name is not nul so it will return value0
                clazz.value0
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You basically have a situation where you have a list of alternatives (`value0`, `value1`, `value2`), and you want to pick the first alternative that is non null. `value0` doesn't quite fit into this, but we can make it fit by using `?.let` as in your attempt, or in general, make any condition fit using `takeIf`.

Then you can just write your alternatives and separate them with the elvis operator `?:`:

```
clazz.value0.takeIf { clazz.name != null } ?: // or clazz.name?.let { clazz.value0 }
clazz.value1 ?:
clazz.value2
```

You can also extract out `clazz` into a `run`:

```
clazz.run {
    value0.takeIf { name != null } ?: 
    value1 ?: 
    value2
}
```

This reads just like English:

> Take `value0` if `name` is not null, otherwise `value1` if it is not null. Otherwise `value2`.

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin, `if` can be used as an expression (like `when`). And it's often more readable than `?.let {..} ?: run {..}`. You could use it this way:

```kotlin
val result = if (clazz.name != null) {
    clazz.value0 
} else {
    clazz.value1 ?: clazz.value2
}
```

Now, as is often the case, isolated pieces of logic like this are best extracted into a separate function. So I would suggest extracting this piece in an extension function on `Clazz`:

```kotlin
val result = clazz.meaningfulNameForThis()


private fun Clazz.meaningfulNameForThis() = if (name != null) {
    value0 
} else {
    value1 ?: value2
}
```